# line number footnotes

Tags: footnotes, linenumber

I managed to create unnumbered footnotes by line number with:

`\linelabel{label1}\blfootnote{\textbf{\lineref{label1}} textline1}`, however a new label1,2,3... is needed for each reference. Can this be solved with `\refstepcounter` or something else?

My current solution has a few issues: `\refstepcounter{counterA}\linelabel{\thecounterA}\blfootnote{\textbf{\lineref{\thecounterA}} line1footnote}`

namely, more than one reference to a line results in the prior line number reference shown as "??". I would like to have additional footnotes from one line referenced by a bullet instead of the line number. Any suggestions much appreciated, very new to TeX...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[modulo, pagewise]{lineno}
\linenumbers
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup}

\newcounter{counterA}
\setcounter{counterA}{1}

\begin{document}

textline1\linelabel{label1}\blfootnote{\textbf{\lineref{label1}} textline1} text text textline2\linelabel{label2}\blfootnote{\textbf{\lineref{label2}} textline2} text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text textline3\linelabel{label3}\blfootnote{\textbf{\lineref{label3}} textline3}

textlineA\refstepcounter{counterA}\linelabel{\thecounterA}\blfootnote{\textbf{\lineref{\thecounterA}} textline1} text text textlineB\refstepcounter{counterA}\linelabel{\thecounterA}\blfootnote{\textbf{\lineref{\thecounterA}} textline1}  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

textlineC\refstepcounter{counterA}\linelabel{\thecounterA}\blfootnote{\textbf{\lineref{\thecounterA}} textline1} text text

\end{document}
```